# Naive way to violate SCH at $\aleph_\omega$

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Silver proved that GCH can fail at a measurable cardinal; using Prikry forcing we get the failure of SCH at a singular cardinal of cofinality $\omega$. It seems that to bring that down to $\aleph_\omega$, one either uses Prikry forcing interleaved with collapse or some extender based forcing. My question is why the most naive thing--Prikry forcing *followed* by collapse-- not work.

Namely, suppose $\kappa=\lim_n\kappa_n$ is strong limit, $\kappa_0=\omega$,  $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$. Let $\mathbb{P}=\prod_n\text{Col}(\kappa_n^+,\kappa_{n+1})$. By choosing $\kappa_n$s appropriately, this forcing should preserve both $\kappa$ and $\kappa^+$, using similar argument as in Easton forcing. It has size $\kappa^{++}$ so cardinals starting from $\kappa^{+++}$ are also preserved. Must it collapse $\kappa^{++}$? All I can see is that if there is a scale on $\prod_n\kappa_n^+$ of length $\kappa^+$ then the forcing seems to collapse $\prod_n\kappa_{n+1}=\kappa^{++}$.

Comment: There is an (at least for me) inaccessible article by Jech (called "On the cofinality of countable products of cardinal numbers", published in "A tribute to Paul Erdos") which shows exactly what you require. The basic construction consists of choosing functions $f_{\xi}$ for $\xi<\kappa^+$ such that $[f_{\xi}]_U=\xi$ and then defining $f_{\xi}^*(n):=f_{\xi}(\kappa_n)$ (where this is below $\kappa_n^+$ and $0$ otherwise). Showing that the sequence $(f_{\xi}^*)_{\xi\in\kappa^+}$ is increasing is easy, i have not managed to show it is cofinal.

Comment: @HannesJakob What if I collapse along something other than the Prikry generic sequence?

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea. The only thing i can think of is using that WLOG every $\kappa_n$ is inaccessible and then forcing instead with $\prod_nCol(\kappa_n,<\kappa_{n+1})$ but i do not have a lot of experience in this topic.